# Missing sounds on iPhone-X

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

I'm not sure what I might have done, but all the sound effects on my iPhone X running iOS 13 seem to have been disabled.

I'm not getting keyboard clicks when I type. And when I send a text or iMessage, there's no swoosh sound, but it does vibrate. When I click the lock screen button, I don't get the feedback sound. When I receive a phone call, text, or iMessage it just vibrates, I don't get the sound effects I've enabled.

I checked the Sound settings, and it looks correct. The volume is in the middle, and "Keyboard Clicks", "Lock Sound", and "System Haptics" are all enabled. It plays my ringtone when I go into the settings screen, and testing all the assigned sound effects works. They just don't play in the appropriate apps.

I was using Waze a couple of days ago, and it was initially trying to send its audio instructions via Bluetooth to my car. I switched it over to the phone's speakers. Could that have affected other sounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you accidentally turned on the “silent mode” switch at the top-left, above the volume buttons? If it’s on, it will show a sliver of red. Do your alarms make a noise? The mute switch doesn’t affect those.

Comment: That was it! I didn't know about that switch. I also bought a magnetic car mount, and I'd taken the phone out of its case to install the plate, I must have flicked the switch accidentally while doing it.